# Can any automation tool(s) notify of metadata changes e.g., a field label?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow, email-alert

Are there any process automation tools that would allow our system administrators to get a notification 60 days after a field name is changed?

Specifically, when a field gets deprecated in our org, we remove visibility for all users, then append OBS_ to the beginning of the field label and leave it for 60 days to give user(s) time to ensure no negative impact. I would like to automate a notification to be emailed to the system admin that made the change so they know when to go in and delete field.

Comment: Are you looking for a pre-built solution, or are you open to developing a solution?

Comment: @sfdcfox We would be open to either option.